# Python script problems with Type Error 'Type' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this email_check class that I use for part of a script I have and lately it has been throwing errors. I had to make a change to the code because it at one point was using google plus and its been throwing errors due to that, I removed google plus from the for statement in the code below and now I get the Type Error 'Type' object is not iterable. Here is the code:

```
from scraper.config import Config
# from scraper.google_plus import GooglePlus
from scraper.scraper import Scraper
from scraper.spokeo import Spokeo


class EmailChecker:
    def __init__(self):
        config = Config()

        # Open instance to chromedriver
        self.__scraper = Scraper()

    def check_email(self, email):
        config = Config()
        results = {}

        # for _ in (GooglePlus, Spokeo):
        for _ in (Spokeo):
            site = _(self.__scraper)

            try:
                result = site.search_for_email(email)
            except Exception:
                if config.debug:
                    raise
                result = None

            try:
                site.logout()
            except Exception:
                if config.debug:
                    raise
                pass

            results[_.__name__] = result

        try:
            self.__scraper.driver.close()
        except Exception:
            pass

        try:
            self.__scraper.driver.quit()
        except Exception:
            pass

        return results
```

Comment: `for _ in (Spokeo,):` (with a comma), or just drop the for altogether and use `_ = Spokeo`. Using `_` as variable name is probably not the best idea though.

Comment: Be careful, a lot of this code is unidiomatic! By convention, naming a variable `_` indicates a value which is unused/thrown away. You’re doing the exact opposite here. `except Exception:` is bad practice. You’re also likely misusing the double underscore (`__`) prefix. If this is all the code for `EmailChecker`, I’m not convinced that a class is the right way to structure this.

Answer (score 1):

`(GooglePlus, Spokeo)` is a tuple, which can be iterated in a `for` loop. `(Spokeo)` is an expression inside a parenthesis, which is only used to denote precedence. For a more concrete example, consider `(2 + 3, 1)` (which evaluates to `(5, 1)`) versus `(2 + 3)` (which evaluates to 5).

To change the code the least, you could just write `(Spokeo,)` instead of `(Spokeo)` to have a one-tuple, though that is a bit weird syntax. Since you're not iterating over anything anymore, you could just drop the for loop:

```
results = {}

_ = Spokeo # the old for was here

site = _(self.__scraper)

...
```

But consider having a better name than `_`. Or just drop that variable and use `Spokeo` explicitly in its place: `site = Spokeo(self.__scraper)` and so on.